# Multiple Apps on one JBoss Instance

Tags: jboss, web-applications

I am trying to find out if it is possible to configure One instance of JBOSS to run multiple apps. Each application serve on a different port and I hope JBoss has this capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's possible on WebLogic.  When I create the domain for a new application I can specify the port.  I'm sure that JBoss has a similar capability.